# spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: apache-camel, spring-boot, swagger, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to use both the spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch andI am having the following when I try to render a static Swagger html page:

---

**Whitelabel Error Page**

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Nov 02 17:44:17 GMT 2014

### There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

How can I get the normal index page to render ?
The static html page stop from been displayed when I added the 
 compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch")
to my dependencies.

I started with simple spring-boot-sample-web-static and it worked until added the spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch

Thank you. Oscar

Comment: I've never used spring-boot but it just sounds like a configuration problem. You should share your configuration as part of the question. In a 'regular' web application, that would be the web.xml and the directory structure where you include the static pages.

Comment: I've just tried adding the a dependency on spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch to the web-static sample and it serves its index page just fine. Can you post some more information about the version of Boot you're using and the exact steps to take to reproduce your problem?

Comment: where does camel into play?

Comment: I was considering using camel for the both ETL and the exposed REST interface but found the Camel REST DSL and Swagger a bit lacking to  what Spring MCV rest controller and Swagger plugin integration does.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found a work around the error happends when using the command
- ***gradle bootRun*** 
to run the execute the code
But if use if use the commmand
- ***gradle run***
It all works ok and the packaged jar runs without problems.